# getting error while doing post request to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

So its a little bit complicated i will try to make it simple.
i have a table with 3 columns and i made function that if u press on the column its give u the id of the post.
after this i need the id so i can show the post over new page - post.php.

i made this request

```
$(".click_title").click(function() {
        var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find(".post_id_c").text();// for sure work
        $.post("post.php",{"post_id_to_show":$item},function(){
                location.href = "post.php";
        });
    });
```

on the php i starting with this:

```
if (isset ($_POST["post_id_to_show"]) ){
    $post_id_to_show = $_POST["post_id_to_show"];
}else{
    echo "errror";
}
```

and now i getting an error from the echo thing.

and then i want to show the post from the sql table:

```
<table class="table">
          
              
                <caption><h3 style="text-align:right">h1</h3></caption>
                <tr class="success">
                    <th style="text-align:center"> h2 
                    <th style="text-align:center"> h3 
                    <th style="text-align:center"> h4
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=:post_id");
                    $cursor->execute( array(":post_id"=>$post_id_to_show) );
                    foreach ($cursor->fetchAll() as $obj): ?>
                <tr>
                     <td style="text-align:center"> <? echo $obj['comment_data']?></td>
                     <td style="text-align:center"><? echo $obj['full_name']?></td>
                     <td style="text-align:center"><? echo $obj['date_time']?></td>
                </tr>
                    <? endforeach; ?>    
            </table>
```

and i getting this error from the web page *Notice: Undefined variable: post_id_to_show in /opt/lampp/htdocs/big_project/post.php on line 96*

btw the line is this line

```
$cursor->execute( array(":post_id"=>$post_id_to_show) );
```

something wrong?

Comment: Are you first trying to post a value using Ajax and then after redirect the client to the same page, trying to use the variable you passed in the previous request?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no, i trying to post request to another page - post.php , but somehow it doesnt get it

Comment: _"but somehow it doesnt get it"_ - How did you determine that? You're just posting a value to `post.php` but you don't do anything with the response from that request. All you're doing is after the ajax post with the id is successful, you redirect the user to `post.php` using GET and without any data. You know that your `$.post(...)` code will create one request and `location.href = 'post.php';` will create a completely different request, not having any of the parameters from the first request, right?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no i didnt knew it, so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

first i deliver the info by ajax like this.

```
$(".click_title").click(function(){
        var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find(".post_id_c").text();//עובד בטוח
        
                if($item){
                    $.ajax({
                url: 'post.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {post_id_to_show:$item},
                success: function(data) {
                    location.href = "post.php";
                    console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

and than in the first call of post_id_to_show i switch it to session var.
in the second call i used the session var and it worked.